# Failed to apply plugin 'com.chaquo.python'

Tags: android, flutter, dart, gradle, chaquopy

I am trying to use the chaquopy flutter plugin. After all the initial setup reported [here](https://pub.dev/packages/chaquopy), I run `flutter run` and get this error:

```
Using hardware rendering with device sdk gphone64 x86 64. If you notice graphics artifacts, consider enabling software rendering with "--enable-software-rendering".
Launching lib/main.dart on sdk gphone64 x86 64 in debug mode...

FAILURE: Build completed with 2 failures.

1: Task failed with an exception.
-----------
* Where:
Build file '/home/alessio/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dev/chaquopy-0.0.19/android/build.gradle' line: 28

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred evaluating project ':chaquopy'.
> Failed to apply plugin 'com.chaquo.python'.
   > Could not find matching constructor for: com.android.build.gradle.internal.api.DefaultAndroidSourceDirectorySet(String, org.gradle.api.internal.project.DefaultProject_Decorated, com.android.build.gradle.internal.api.artifact.SourceArtifactType$JAVA_SOURCES)

* Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.
==============================================================================

2: Task failed with an exception.
-----------
* Where:
Script '/home/alessio/snap/flutter/common/flutter/packages/flutter_tools/gradle/flutter.gradle' line: 395

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred configuring project ':chaquopy'.
> Failed to notify project evaluation listener.
   > Could not find matching constructor for: com.android.build.gradle.internal.api.DefaultAndroidSourceDirectorySet(String, org.gradle.api.internal.project.DefaultProject_Decorated, com.android.build.gradle.internal.api.artifact.SourceArtifactType$JAVA_SOURCES)
   > Cannot invoke method substring() on null object
   > com.android.builder.errors.EvalIssueException: compileSdkVersion is not specified. Please add it to build.gradle

* Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.
==============================================================================

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 1s
Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...                           2,183ms
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1
```

this is the output of `./gradlew --refresh-dependencies --warning-mode all`:

```
> Configure project :chaquopy
The RepositoryHandler.jcenter() method has been deprecated. This is scheduled to be removed in Gradle 8.0. JFrog announced JCenter's sunset in February 2021. Use mavenCentral() instead. Consult the upgrading guide for further information: https://docs.gradle.org/7.5/userguide/upgrading_version_6.html#jcenter_deprecation
        at build_8i1n964jy2rxqs9w3xv7zw649$_run_closure1$_closure2.doCall(/home/alessio/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dev/chaquopy-0.0.19/android/build.gradle:8)
        (Run with --stacktrace to get the full stack trace of this deprecation warning.)

FAILURE: Build completed with 2 failures.

1: Task failed with an exception.
-----------
* Where:
Build file '/home/alessio/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dev/chaquopy-0.0.19/android/build.gradle' line: 28

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred evaluating project ':chaquopy'.
> Failed to apply plugin 'com.chaquo.python'.
   > Could not find matching constructor for: com.android.build.gradle.internal.api.DefaultAndroidSourceDirectorySet(String, org.gradle.api.internal.project.DefaultProject_Decorated, com.android.build.gradle.internal.api.artifact.SourceArtifactType$JAVA_SOURCES)

* Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.
==============================================================================

2: Task failed with an exception.
-----------
* Where:
Script '/home/alessio/snap/flutter/common/flutter/packages/flutter_tools/gradle/flutter.gradle' line: 395

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred configuring project ':chaquopy'.
> Failed to notify project evaluation listener.
   > Could not find matching constructor for: com.android.build.gradle.internal.api.DefaultAndroidSourceDirectorySet(String, org.gradle.api.internal.project.DefaultProject_Decorated, com.android.build.gradle.internal.api.artifact.SourceArtifactType$JAVA_SOURCES)
   > Cannot invoke method substring() on null object
   > com.android.builder.errors.EvalIssueException: compileSdkVersion is not specified. Please add it to build.gradle

* Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.
==============================================================================

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 15s
```

this is the log produced by `./gradlew help --scan`: https://scans.gradle.com/s/nddzq6gl7fpy2

this is the output of `./gradlew -v`:

```
------------------------------------------------------------
Gradle 7.5
------------------------------------------------------------

Build time:   2022-07-14 12:48:15 UTC
Revision:     c7db7b958189ad2b0c1472b6fe663e6d654a5103

Kotlin:       1.6.21
Groovy:       3.0.10
Ant:          Apache Ant(TM) version 1.10.11 compiled on July 10 2021
JVM:          17.0.6 (JetBrains s.r.o. 17.0.6+0-17.0.6b802.4-9586694)
OS:           Linux 5.15.0-78-generic amd64
```

this is my top level `build.gradle`:

```
buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.7.10'
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
        maven { url "https://chaquo.com/maven" }
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.3.0'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
        classpath "com.chaquo.python:gradle:14.0.2"
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
}

rootProject.buildDir = '../build'
subprojects {
    project.buildDir = "${rootProject.buildDir}/${project.name}"
}
subprojects {
    project.evaluationDependsOn(':app')
}

tasks.register("clean", Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

this is my `android/app/build.gradle`:

```
def localProperties = new Properties()
def localPropertiesFile = rootProject.file('local.properties')
if (localPropertiesFile.exists()) {
    localPropertiesFile.withReader('UTF-8') { reader ->
        localProperties.load(reader)
    }
}

def flutterRoot = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.sdk')
if (flutterRoot == null) {
    throw new GradleException("Flutter SDK not found. Define location with flutter.sdk in the local.properties file.")
}

def flutterVersionCode = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionCode')
if (flutterVersionCode == null) {
    flutterVersionCode = '1'
}

def flutterVersionName = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionName')
if (flutterVersionName == null) {
    flutterVersionName = '1.0'
}

apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'com.chaquo.python'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply from: "$flutterRoot/packages/flutter_tools/gradle/flutter.gradle"

android {
    namespace "com.example.prova"
    compileSdkVersion localProperties.getProperty('flutter.compileSdkVersion').toInteger()
    ndkVersion flutter.ndkVersion

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }

    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = '1.8'
    }

    sourceSets {
        main.java.srcDirs += 'src/main/kotlin'
    }

    defaultConfig {
        // TODO: Specify your own unique Application ID (https://developer.android.com/studio/build/application-id.html).
        applicationId "com.example.prova"
        // You can update the following values to match your application needs.
        // For more information, see: https://docs.flutter.dev/deployment/android#reviewing-the-gradle-build-configuration.
        minSdkVersion localProperties.getProperty('flutter.minSdkVersion').toInteger()
        targetSdkVersion localProperties.getProperty('flutter.targetSdkVersion').toInteger()
        versionCode flutterVersionCode.toInteger()
        versionName flutterVersionName
        ndk {
            abiFilters "armeabi-v7a", "arm64-v8a", "x86", "x86_64"
        }
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            // TODO: Add your own signing config for the release build.
            // Signing with the debug keys for now, so `flutter run --release` works.
            signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
        }
    }
}

flutter {
    source '../..'
}

dependencies {
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
}
```

and this is my `local.properties`:

```
sdk.dir=/home/alessio/Android/Sdk
flutter.sdk=/home/alessio/snap/flutter/common/flutter
flutter.buildMode=debug
flutter.versionName=1.0.0
flutter.versionCode=1
flutter.minSdkVersion=21
flutter.targetSdkVersion=34
flutter.compileSdkVersion=34
```

I don know how to fix it, if you can help me I would be very glad.

Comment: module level build.gradle?

Comment: @MidasLefko added in my question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This error is either caused by using incompatible versions of the Chaquopy and Android Gradle plugins, or the Chaquopy plugin misdetecting the Android plugin's version number.

This is itself caused by the mismatching version numbers between your build.gradle file:

```
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.3.0'
        classpath "com.chaquo.python:gradle:14.0.2"
```

... and the Chaquopy Flutter plugin's build.gradle file, whose path is shown under `chaquopy-0.0.19` above:

```
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.1.0'
        classpath "com.chaquo.python:gradle:12.0.0"
```

I was able to work around this by editing the `chaquopy-0.0.19` build.gradle file as follows:

- Update the version numbers to match those in your own build.gradle file.
- Increase the `minSdkVersion` to 21, to fix the error "This version of Chaquopy requires minSdkVersion 21 or higher".

This allowed `flutter run` to build and run [your app](https://github.com/alesspalma/prova).

(I am the developer of Chaquopy, which is being actively maintained. However, the Chaquopy *Flutter* plugin is an unofficial third-party project whose developer has been inactive for nearly a year, so I can't recommend using it.)

Comment: thanks! can you tell me where to find the "chaquopy-0.0.19 file" ?

Comment: It's in the error message.